# web2py validators in controller

Tags: validation, web2py

Is it possible to use web2py validators like IS_NOT_EMPTY() in the controller? They seem to be imported but in the controller, however they are not useful at all. Which parameters should I use when calling them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Validators are generally specified as the `requires` attribute of DAL Field objects, typically when the models are defined. You can also specify the `requires` attribute of a Field in a controller (this is typically done when validators or their arguments are conditional and not determined until a particular contoller action is called). When generating a `FORM` object manually, you can also assign validators to the `requires` attribute of the form helpers, such as `INPUT`, `SELECT`, etc.

You can also instantiate and call validators directly, though this is less common. To do so, first instantiate the validator object (possibly passing arguments if the validator constructor takes any), and then call the object by passing in a single value to be validated. The validator will return a 2-tuple -- the first element will be the validated value (possibly transformed if the validator does a transformation), and the second will be either `None` or an error message (if validation failed). For example:

```
>>> IS_EMAIL()('bademail')
('bademail', 'enter a valid email address')
>>> IS_EMAIL()('goodemail@email.com')
('goodemail@email.com', None)
```